# Delete element of list in pool.map() python

Tags: python, list, python-multiprocessing

```
    processPool.map(parserMethod, ((inputFile[line:line + chunkSize], sharedQueue) for line in xrange(0, lengthOfFile, chunkSize)))
```

1. Here, I am passing control to parserMethod with a tuple of params inputFile[line:line + chunkSize] and a sharedQueue.

Can anyone tell me how I can delete the elements of inputFile[line:line + chunkSize] after it is passed to the parserMethod ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

```
del inputFile[line:line + chunkSize]
```

will remove those items.  However, your map is stepping through the entire file, which makes me wonder: are you trying to remove them as they're parsed?  This requires the map or parser to alter an input argument, which invites trouble.

If you're only trying to save memory usage, it's a little late: you already saved the entire file in InputFile.  If you need only to clean up after the parsing, then use the extreme form of **del**ete, once, after the parsing is finished:

```
del inputFile[:]
```

If you want to reduce the memory requirement up front, you have to back up a step.  Instead of putting the entire file into a list, try making an nice input pipeline.  You didn't post the context of this code, so I'm going to use a generic case with a couple of name assumptions:

```
def line_chunk_stream(input_stream, chunk_size):
    # Generator to return a stream of paring units,
    #   <chunk_size> lines each.
    # To make sure you could check the logic here,
    #   I avoided several Pythonic short-cuts.
    line_count = 0
    parse_chunk = []
    for line in input_stream:
        line_count += 1
        parse_chunk.append(line)
        if line_count % chunk_size == 0:
            yield parse_chunk
            del parse_chunk[:]

input_stream = open("source_file", 'r')
parse_stream = line_chunk_stream(input_stream, chunk_size)
parserMethod(parse_stream)
```

I hope that at least one of these solves your underlying problem.

Comment: I see. I want to minimize the memory utilization. So the 3rd Solution applies for my problem. However, I am apparently not allowed to use yield while using a .map() function, as worker processes are involved. It gives me the following error:

        "cPickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'generator'>: attribute lookup __builtin__.generator failed"

Comment: Right.  Note that there's no **map** in my sample code.  The generator does it "from inside": parserMethod gets called on each yielded block, in turn.